# How to get device ip - Expo React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ip, expo

How can I get the ip of the device using React Native and Expo,

I'm trying this and all I see on the alert is [object promise].

I'm running the app on an emulator and on the browser..

```
import * as Network from 'expo-network';
alert(Network.getIpAddressAsync());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is written in the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/network/#networkgetipaddressasync), the method Network.getIpAddressAsync() returns a Promise that resolves to a String of the current IP address of the device's main network interface.
Due to this fact, you need to wait for the promise to finish as it is asynchronous.

You can do so by either attaching the await keyword before it, like this:

```
await Network.getIpAddressAsync();
```

or by chaining a then function afterwards, like so:

```
Network.getIpAddressAsync().then(function(address) {
//Your logic here
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

`Network.getIpAddressAsync()` returns a `Promise`, so you need to resolve it first.

```
import * as Network from 'expo-network';

const ipAlert = async () => {
  const ip = await Network.getIpAddressAsync()
  alert(ip);
};

ipAlert();
```